# ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_13 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value

Tags: python

```
    path=os.path.join(DATADIR,category)
    class_num=CATEGORIES.index(category)
    for i in os.listdir(path):
        img=os.path.join(path,i)
        img=load_img(img,target_size=(100,100))
        img_array=img_to_array(img)
        img_array = np.expand_dims(img_array, axis=0)
        image=preprocess_input(img_array)
        # extract features
        scores = model.predict(image)
        sim_class = np.argmax(scores)
```

If I run this code, I take this error in model.predict stage :ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_13 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 1 but received input with shape (None, 100, 100, 3)
Can you help me?

Comment: Probably the array `image` has other dimensions than what the function `model.predict()` expects it to have. Your passing an array that has `3` as the dimension of its last axis but the function expects this axis to have dimension `1`. Possibly `preprocess_input` should be converting the array representing the image to gray-scale (which it currently does not...).

Comment: What can I do ?